# react redux hash based routing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-routing

I have a router like:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login} />
        <Route path="/#!login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/#!first" component={First} />
        <Route path="/#!second" component={Second} />
        </Route>
  </Router>
```

and I have a header component like :

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3><Link to="/#!first">First</Link></h3>
        <h3><Link to="/#!second">Second</Link></h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

Now when I click `First` in my headers it does not redirect me to that link..

How can I implement hash based routing in react and redux

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hashHistory`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#hashhistory), and let all your routes should be aware of your history. Do this instead:

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';

<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="first" component={First} />
        <Route path="second" component={Second} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Link it like this:

```
<Link to="/first">First</Link>
```

And let the router do the rest.

Comment: what if I want hash based routing.. ?? I know this works I have implemented this though but I want to have hash based routing..

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you so much! I do get some weird crap appended to the end of the page though like a random string it looks like `#/?_k=d74z39` or `#/contact?_k=uxnbcv`

Comment: You can read more about it in [#1967](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1967).

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `'react-router' does not contain an export named 'hashHistory'.` on `"react-router": "^4.2.0"`

Comment: As you can see in the [CHANGES.md](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md), it was pre v2 back then (`2.0.0` was actually released a day later).